# convert array of variants to std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, variadic

I am working on a C++11 wrapper for a variant type implemented in C.  The variant type supports common data types like int, float, string, but also **tuples**.  I have converters for the basic types of the form...

```
template<typename T>
T convert_to(const Variant &var);
```

... but I am struggling with conversion to std::tuple.

The underlying C API can break out a tuple by returning an array of Variants.  It looks something like this:

```
int get_tuple(Variant var, Variant **argv, int *argc);
```

Now I recognize I can manually create templates for each size of tuple, but I am looking for a variadic solution that can handle any size of tuple.  Any tips on how to approach this?

BTW, the actual thing that I'm trying to wrap is the Erlang NIF API.

Comment: Does this concept of a tuple readily maps to `std::tuple`? It seems that its arity is available at runtime, not compile-time. If the possible number of arities if known and small, you could type-erase your way out of this, but the final interface for that type would not look like that of `std::tuple`.

Comment: I intend to throw an exception if the Variant tuple arity does not match the std::tuple arity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using C++11 (and you know the tuple type from the template parameter), you can happily use variadic templates. Something like*

```
template <class ... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> convert_to(const Variant& v)
{
  Variant tmp_array[std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Ts...>>::value];
  get_tuple(v, tmp_array, sizeof(tmp_array)/sizeof(tmp_array[0]));
  std::tuple<Ts...> ret;
  array_to_tuple(ret, tmp_array);
  return ret;
}
```

where `array_to_tuple` will copy the elements one by one:

```
template <class ... Ts>
struct array_to_tupler
{
  template <int I>
  static void do_it(std::tuple<Ts...> &t, Variant* vs)
  {
    std::get<I-1>(t) = convert_to<decltype(std::get<I-1>(t))>(vs[I-1]);
    do_it<I-1>(t, vs);
  }
  template <>
  static void do_it<0>(std::tuple<Ts...> &t, Variant* vs)
  {
  }
};

template <int N, class ... Ts>
void array_to_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...> &t, Variant (&vs)[N])
{
  array_to_tupler<Ts...>::do_it<N>(t, vs);
}
```

Hope this can work...

*) Note that such `convert_to` will not be easily callable. I suggest doing the specialization on the return types with class templates, because you need partial specialization, which function template cannot have.

Comment: It is illegal to have function specialization inside a template class, but it works if you flip it inside-out (array_to_tupler is templatized on int N, do_it is templatized on Ts...).  Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.